# undefined method `require' for Rack::Builder

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

When i try to start my Sinatra app via `rackup` command i get this error:

```
/home/matteog/Scrivania/ruby_ws/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>': undefined method `require' for #<Rack::Builder:0x000000027d4e50> (NoMethodError)
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/matteog/Scrivania/ruby_ws/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/matteog/Scrivania/ruby_ws/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/matteog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

But i have no problems when i use `ruby helloworld.rb`. My `config.ru` is very simple:

```
require 'helloworld'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Furthermore i successfully executed `bundle install` before `rackup`, with this Gemfile (output omitted):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'sinatra', '>= 1.4.5', '~> 1.4'
gem 'sinatra-contrib', '>= 1.4.2', '~> 1.4'
gem 'dm-core', '>= 1.2.0', '~> 1.2'
gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter', '>= 1.2.0', '~> 1.2'
gem 'dm-validations', '>= 1.2.0', '~> 1.2'
gem 'dm-timestamps', '>= 1.2.0', '~> 1.2'
gem 'dm-migrations', '>= 1.2.0', '~> 1.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'minitest'
end
```

Comment: Can you check `Gemfile.lock` to see which version of the `rack` gem is used? Try adding a `gem 'rack', '~> 1.6.4'` to the `Gemfile`, maybe you have an old buggy version.

Comment: Also, try `bundle exec rackup config.ru`

Comment: I think is not an old version problem, since i'm already using rack 1.6.4. But to be sure i tried anyway what you suggested with no luck...

Comment: Very odd. Is there any more stacktrace or just that one line? Could you maybe try a different ruby version?

Comment: I Updated the question with the complete stacktrace

Comment: What do you get if you change it to `Kernel.require 'helloworld'`?

Comment: /home/matteog/Scrivania/ruby_ws/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `Kernel' for #<Rack::Builder:0x000000021113e8> (NameError)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104577/discussion-between-matt-and-leventix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104577/discussion-between-matt-and-leventix) - summary for anyone having the same issue:

If I paste it into VIM, I get:

```
undefined method `<feff>require' for
```

Unicode 0xFEFF is the [BOM character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), probably inserted by the editor.

Comment: Good catch. I think this is arguably a bug in Rack – it would make sense for it to strip out the BOM if present.